# Is there a way for me to manipulate this 7 inside the podeConter() method?

Tags: java, object

I want to be able to manipulate the 7 created by q1.lado inside of the podeConter() method, but I don't know how to call it there. I know that I can use the q2.lado = 6 there by just using q.lado, but that does not apply to q1.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circulo c1 = new Circulo();
        c1.raio = 5;

        System.out.println(c1.calcularArea());
        System.out.println(c1.calcularPerimetro());

        Quadrado q1 = new Quadrado();
        q1.lado = 7;  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        Quadrado q2 = new Quadrado();
        q2.lado = 6;

        System.out.println(q1.podeConter(q2)); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Quadrado {
    public double lado;


    public double calcularArea(){
        return lado * lado;
    }

    public double calcularPerimetro(){
        return 4 * lado;
    }

    public boolean podeConter(Quadrado q){ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `podeConter` on the `q1` instance. So just `lado` or `this.lado` lets you access  the field of `q1`

Answer (score 0):

Sure; you call `q1.podeConter(q2)` which means the 'receiver' of the `podeConter` method is whatever `q1` is pointing at.

Which is exactly the instance whose `lado` field you want to modify. So, just.. do so.

```
public boolean podeConter(Quadrado q) {
    lado = 5;
    return true;
}
```

One way of thinking about it is that all non-static methods have an invisible extra parameter of the type the method is in, and it is called 'this'. Any reference to a field or other method will use 'this' as default. Your `podeConter` method therefore has 2 'parameters' of type `Quadrado`; one is called `this`, the other is called `q`. If you write `lado = 5`, that's shorthand for `this.lado = 5;`.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know about the existence of the "this" parameter, that worked perfectly thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Java is pass-by-reference for objects.  When you pass `q1` as the argument to `podeConter(Quadrado q)`, the object reference named `q` refers to the exact same object as `q1` (not a copy).  This allows you to access its properties and manipulate that object within the method using the local variable `q`.

```
public boolean podeConter(Quadrado q) {
  return q.lado <= this.lado;
}
```